# Winding arrangement in small toroidal mains isolation transformer

Tags: transformer, isolation, winding

I got a 0.3A 220/220 toroidal transformer with the primary (red wires) on the outside and the secondary (black wires) on the inside.

What is the reasoning behind this arrangement in this particular case if any (and if it's even a standard)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible Reason #1

The supplier may pre-wind the secondaries to suit common applications then, when they receive an order for a bunch of transformers having (say) a 220 volt input they wind the primary to suit the order. But equally, it could be done the other way round for very similar reasons.

Possible Reason #2

I expect it might be to avoid the much thinner primary wires being damaged when winding the much sturdier secondary wires over the primary.